# Java dynamic return type?

Tags: java, generics, types

I have a container (List) of some elements of type T and want to filter it. So it contains only elements of a specific subtype U. Would it be possible to set a "dynamic" return type?

example:

```
class SomeContainer<T> extends ArrayList<T>{

    public SomeContainer<T> subset(Class c){
        SomeContainer<...here the type of c > output = new SomeContainer<.. also ..>();

        //filter own elements and only add c-objects in the new list

        return output;
    }
}
```

At the moment it returns a list of the generic type T and not of the c-Class-type (Subtype of T). Therefore I sometimes receive the following Compiler-Notice:

```
Note: SomeContainer.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Because I want to filter the list after objects of a subtype and trigger subtype-specific methods I would need a specific subtype list.

Comment: The warning is because you are using `Class` instead of `Class<?>`. And I am not sure that you can use dynamic types in template parameters.

Comment: *So it contains only elements of a specific subtype U* Why not declare with that specific subtype U?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`java.lang.Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) is a generic type parameterized on itself, so you can use its type parameter, like this:

```
public <U extends T> SomeContainer<U> subset(Class<U> c){
    SomeContainer<U> output = new SomeContainer<U>();
    for (T val : this) {
        if (c.isInstance(val)) {
            output.add(c.cast(val));
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Or better, `output.add(c.cast(val))` to avoid the unchecked cast warning.

Comment: @IanRoberts Absolutely! Thanks for a great suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Generics are a compile-time artefact only, therefore your scheme can't work. The compiler cannot predict what class you will want at each execution of the line of code that makes a call to this function. You cannot make this solution type-safe **unless** you have a very constrained, and quite useless, case where you only ever use class literals to call your function. That would, however almost certainly defeat its purpose to be, as you stated, dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

First point: you can remove the unchecked operation warning by replacing `Class c` argument with `Class<T> c`.  That may be all you need... in which case...  =:-)

Second point:
Usually the code calling SomeContainer.subset() would know at compile type the type U (from the logic context).  This must be the case for you, otherwise you wouldn't be able to pass the `Class c` argument in.

Try:

```
class SomeContainer<T> extends ArrayList<T>{

    public <U extends T> SomeContainer subset(Class<U> c){
        SomeContainer<U> output = new SomeContainer<U>();  
        // put filtered elements into output

        return output;    
    }
}
```

See what I did there?
Introduced a second type param on the method call: `U extends T`. 
Also used this in the argument with `Class<U> c`.
The caller would invoke like (where X is chosen subclass of T):

```
SomeContainer<X> mySubset = mySomeContainer.subset(X.class);     // type inference
SomeContainer<X> mySubset = mySomeContainer.<X>subset(X.class);  // type arg specified
```

---

---

If you need something more dynamic than this, wildcards can assist - allowing a "family" of parametised types to be passed in & out:

```
public SomeContainer<? extends X> subset(Class<? extends X> c){
```

This is a "plastic" function interface: you can return `SomeContainer<T>` or `SomeContainer<X>` for any X which is a subclass of T. The following also works:

```
public SomeContainer<? super Z> subset(Class<? extends X> c){
```

However, as another poster has said, generics are a compile time construct, they are replaced during compile with generated non-generic code.  This means you cannot dynamically decide on the type used to instantiate a generic type with a single line of code.  But you can cheat a little:  If you have a limited number of subclasses of T, say X, Y and Z, where Z extends Y, and Y extends Z, then you can use a good-old hacky "if statement".  Try:

class SomeContainer extends ArrayList{

```
public SomeContainer<? extends X> subset(Class<? extends X> c){
    SomeContainer<? extends X> output = null;

    // would like to use:  "if (c instance of Class<Z>)"
    // but instanceof does not allow generic type arguments
    if (c.getName().equals(Z.class.getName())) {
        SomeContainer<Z> outputZ = new SomeContainer<Z>();
        // put filtered elements into outputZ
        output = outputZ;
    } else if (c.getName().equals(Y.class.getName())) {
        SomeContainer<Y> outputY = new SomeContainer<Y>();
        // put filtered elements into outputZ
        output = outputY;
    } else if (c.getName().equals(X.class.getName())) {
        SomeContainer<X> outputX = new SomeContainer<X>();
        // put filtered elements into outputZ
        output = outputX;
    }
    return output;    
}
```

}

Easy! (or not)  =:-)